# Syntax error for template struct instantiation inside assert statement

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error

For the following template struct defined in a header:

```
#include <unordered_set>

namespace Utilities::ContainerHelpers
{
    template <template <class> class TContainer, class TVal>
    struct is_unique
    {
        bool operator()(TContainer<TVal> const& container) const
        {
            std::unordered_set<TVal, typename TVal::HashFunc> 
                uniqueSubset(container.begin(), container.end());

            return container.size() == uniqueSubset.size();
        }
    };
}
```

I get a syntax error when used in the context of an assert:

```
assert(Utilities::ContainerHelpers::is_unique< std::vector, TelemDetail >{}(telem_detail_obj);
```

but not when defined as a temporary outside of the assert. The `TelemDetail` type is not significant, just contains a nested `HashFunc` struct type.

> warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'assert'
>
> error C2059: syntax error: ')'

Feels like I'm missing something obvious? Compiled with MSVC 2019 -std=c++17

Comment: Compiles on [msvc but fails on gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/61coqs). So some information is missing.

Comment: Seems to work if I wrap the assert argument it inside another set of brackets, but I don't know why?

Comment: If you'd like for others to figure out why, you need to show a [mre].

Comment: @M.A you've missed the point. You should post code which reproduces the issue as closely as possible. We should not have problems to reproduce the issue. Anyway PiotrNycz was able to fill the blanks and provided an answer.

Comment: One more improvement could be made: use variadic in your args: `template <class...> class TContainer` - e.g. std::vector has two args - not just one (the second is defaulted to `std::allocator<T>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert`, as every macro, does not understand C++, it treats every comma `,` as arguments separator:

```
assert(is_unique< std::vector, TelemDetail >{}(session_details));
//    (   first arg          ,  second arg                     )
//
```

But preprocessor macro "understands" `()` - so just add extra pair of `()`:

`assert((is_unique< std::vector, TelemDetail >{}(session_details)));`

Comment: "comma", not "colon"